# Change font for plain text files linked via IncludePicture

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I insert plain text files in Word via IncludeText field,

```
{ IncludeText file.txt }
```

the text is always in Courier font. How I can change it something different, for example Consolas?

I tried make changes in styles, but there is no effect.

I use Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CHARFORMAT switch in the field.  Then just apply the formatting you want to the "I" in INCLUDETEXT in the field switch.  The CHARFORMAT tells Word to format the text displayed in the field as per the first character (ie the "I").  See example screenshot below with Consolas font, bold large font and red.

[image]